# Rails FullCalendar Creating Multiple Events

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalendar https://fullcalendar.io/docs/ in my Rails Application and the scenario is that I have to create multiple shifts using this calendar like on Monday it can be 9 AM - 6 PM, Tuesday 11 AM - 8 PM and on Friday 3 PM - 6 PM once at a time.

Please have a look on snapshot below:

[snapshot of form which I have to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2X29i.png)

So as in the snapshot user will select the time interval like on Monday 9 AM - 6 PM, Tuesday 11 AM - 8 PM and on Friday 3 PM - 6 PM and when he will click on Save button then I want to save all these values in the database.

I have already integrate this full calendar in another places in my application like for simply creating a single event but here the problem is that I have to create multiple events on one click.

The approach which coming in my mind that I have to send all the start and end time in the parameters like for example suppose on Monday user select 9 AM - 6 PM then parameters can be {:Monday=> [9am-6pm], :Tuesday=>[11am-8pm]} something like but I am not sure will it be really good solution ?.

Comment: Ok. And what have you tried so far? What research have you done? What problem are you having? This isn't a free write-my-code service. Generally on SO you have more chance of getting help if it looks like you at least tried to help yourself before asking. If you have some existing code, please show it. Also the requirement is not completely clear. You want to define some pre-defined time periods, is that right? And the user must select one or more of those, and then save? The time periods must be of fixed length, yes...or no? What happens if the "part-time" radio button is chosen?

Comment: https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/fullcalendar-events-and-scheduling

Comment: @ADyson I have edit my question please have a look again and regarding your query I am talking about full time period.

Comment: @HardikUpadhyay I already saw this video and wrote the same code and implemented but here as I have mentioned the scenario is different creating multiple events.

Comment: @AnandShrivastava above link is just a reference, saving single record or multiple is totally depend on your logic and requirement. your requirement can be satisfied with same logic with minor changes.

Comment: if you want to save multiple items at one time, then simply keep a record of them in a JS array in-memory - each time the user adds an event, instead of sending it direct to the server, add it to your array. Then finally when they click "save" just send the whole array to the server instead.